# Does service pack need to be reapplied after SQL Server Standard to Enterprise upgrade

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am upgrading SQL Server from **2008 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 1** to **2008 R2 Enterprise Edition** as per the instructions at [Upgrade to a Different Edition of SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707783%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

In the past whenever I have upgraded software in such a manner, I had to re-apply the service pack.

Does a SQL edition upgrade require a service pack re-install ? The MS documentation doesn't talk about it.

```
select @@version
```

after the upgrade gives me

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2011
00:54:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition
(64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Comment: Why not just apply [Service Pack 2](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/07/26/sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-2-is-available.aspx) and [Service Pack 2 Cumulative Update #1](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/08/01/sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-2-cumulative-update-1-is-available.aspx)?

Comment: I agree, if it's not needed it'll say so

Comment: @AaronBertrand Does SP2 Cumulative Update #1 need to applied after SP2 ?

Comment: If you want the fixes from SP1 CU6 & CU7 since they weren't included in SP2. I recommend it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand My question is SP2 Cumulative Update 1 really cumulative ? Does it need SP2 applied first ?

Comment: Yes, you can only apply SP2 CU1 after you've applied SP2. Cumulative updates are only cumulative for the SP they belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the service pack needs to be re-applied - if you run the service pack setup it shouldn't identify this instance as a valid target since the @@VERSION is already at the SP level.

That said, why not just apply [Service Pack 2](https://sqlblog.org/2012/07/26/sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-2-is-available) and [Service Pack 2 Cumulative Update #1](https://sqlblog.org/2012/08/01/sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-2-cumulative-update-1-is-available)?